# How to insert a bulleted list from a text box?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I need to make a bulleted list in word.  It gets the input from a Multi-Line text box.  Each new line that is started on the multt-line text box should produce a new bullet point.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve: [image: Input] [image: Result]

Here is the code that I have, which generates text that was already inputted. (BTW it is not mine)

```
Paragraph assets = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();

assets.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
string[] bulletItems = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };

for (int i = 0; i < bulletItems.Length; i++)
{
    string bulletItem = bulletItems[i];
    if (i < bulletItems.Length - 1)
        bulletItem = bulletItem + "\n";
    assets.Range.InsertBefore(bulletItem);
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to make each line a different variable so i can insert them in string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly what you're trying to achieve, but as I understand it you're trying to insert bullets before each line in a TextBox and then trying to put that text into Word?

Maybe this snippet of code will help you.

```
string[] unbulleted = textBox1.Lines;
string[] bulleted = new string[unbulleted.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < bulleted.Length; i++)
    bulleted[i] = "\u2022" + unbulleted[i];
```

So now you have a string[] with bullets before each string! I'm not sure how one inserts it into Word though.

Comment: Thank you! Just one question, what does the "\u2022" mean?

Comment: That is the Unicode value for a bullet point. You can find a full list of them [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm)!

Comment: To explain a little further, "u2022" is the actual value and the back black slash "\" tells the computer not to take the string literally and to substitute in the corresponding Unicode character.